# Simple dlib program makes my computer crash

Tags: python, opencv, boost-python, dlib

I'm running a simple program with python 3.6 64 bit on pycharm 64bit.

However about two out of three times I run it, my computer suddenly freezes, I can't do anything else and I have to turn it off by pressing the power button.

I suspect it does use too much RAM but I'm not sure where it comes from.

Here is the code :

```
from imutils import face_utils
import numpy as np
import argparse
import imutils
import dlib
import cv2

detector = dlib.get_frontal_face_detector()
predictor = dlib.shape_predictor("shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat")

image = cv2.imread("obama.jpg")
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

rects = detector(gray, 1)


for (i, rect) in enumerate(rects):

    shape = predictor(gray, rect)
    shape = face_utils.shape_to_np(shape)
    (x, y, w, h) = face_utils.rect_to_bb(rect)
    cv2.rectangle(image, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 2)
    cv2.putText(image, "Face #{}".format(i + 1), (x - 10, y - 10),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (0, 255, 0), 2)
    for (x, y) in shape:
        cv2.circle(image, (x, y), 1, (0, 0, 255), -1)

cv2.imshow("Output", image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: Why do you suspect it is using too much RAM?  Have you monitored other system bottle-necks, like paging , disc, and network IO?  Which OS are you using?

Comment: It was only a supposition as I can't monitor anything : a few seconds after i launch the program everything freezes on my computer :/
I am using windows 8.1

Comment: Start the monitor before you run the program, have it in view on one part of your screen, then start your run while you watch the indicators.

Comment: Ok I did it and my processor and Disk 0 reached 100% during use (my computer didn't crash this time, lucky me)
Memory usage is perfectly fine in fact

Answer (score 1):

Well thanks to cdarke I found out that passing my battery usage to "high performances" solved the problem.